# Testing cache in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, caching, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have a code where I am applying caching to get an object.

service:

```kotlin
@Service
class UserServiceImpl(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) : UserService {

    override fun create(userEntity: UserEntity): UserEntity = userRepository.save(userEntity)
        .also { log.info("saved user {}", it) }

    @Cacheable("users", key = "#id")
    override fun get(id: Long): UserEntity = userRepository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow { EntityNotFoundException("User not found by id $id") }
        .also { log.info("from db: received user {}", it) }

    companion object {
        private val log = KotlinLogging.logger { }
    }
}
```

repository:

```kotlin
@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
}
```

I have verified with a simple controller that the caching works well, but I cannot verify this with tests. Test fails with an error: `Verification failed: call 1 of 1: UserRepository(#1).findById(eq(1))). 3 matching calls found, but needs at least 1 and at most 1 calls`

```kotlin
class UserServiceImplTest {
    private val userRepository = mockkClass(UserRepository::class)
    private val userService: UserService = UserServiceImpl(userRepository)

    @Test
    fun `get should use caching`() {
        // given
        val user = UserEntity(1, "Anna", "anna@gmail.com")

        every { userRepository.save(user)} returns user
        every { userRepository.findById(user.id!!) } returns Optional.of(user)

        // when
        userService.get(user.id!!)
        userService.get(user.id!!)
        userService.get(user.id!!)

        // then
        verify(exactly = 1) { userRepository.findById(user.id!!) }
    }
}
```

Perhaps I need to somehow enable caching for tests too. Or my test is written incorrectly (which is most likely). How can I write a test to check that the caching is working?

Answer (score 0):

`@Cacheable` will generate a wrapper method which does the caching. This wrapper will exist on the proxy generated by Spring, so it will not come into play when you create the `UserServiceImpl` yourself. If you want to test it, you need to let Spring context manage the classes, including the mock.

For instance,

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceImplTest {
    @MockBean
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userService: UserService

    @Test
    fun `get should use caching`() {
        // given
        val user = UserEntity(1, "Anna", "anna@gmail.com")

        every { userRepository.save(user)} returns user
        every { userRepository.findById(user.id!!) } returns Optional.of(user)

        // when
        userService.get(user.id!!)
        userService.get(user.id!!)
        userService.get(user.id!!)

        // then
        verify(exactly = 1) { userRepository.findById(user.id!!) }
    }
}
```

Comment: `you need to let Spring context manage the classes, including the mock.` - How can I do that?

Comment: Updated answer to show an example. Unclear whether you're using MockK or Mockito. For MockK you'll need to use [this dependency](https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk) and `@MockkBean` instead.